# How can I find which operating system my Ruby program is running on?

Tags: ruby, operating-system

I want my Ruby program to do different things on a Mac than on Windows. How can I find out on which system my program is running?

Comment: Related: [Detecting Linux distribution/platform in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25970280/5389585)

Answer (score 158):

Use the `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant, and optionally wrap it in a module to make it more friendly:

```
module OS
  def OS.windows?
    (/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  end

  def OS.mac?
   (/darwin/ =~ RUBY_PLATFORM) != nil
  end

  def OS.unix?
    !OS.windows?
  end

  def OS.linux?
    OS.unix? and not OS.mac?
  end

  def OS.jruby?
    RUBY_ENGINE == 'jruby'
  end
end
```

It is not perfect, but works well for the platforms that I do development on, and it's easy enough to extend.

Comment: for jruby, you're better off using `RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"]` to get your OS.

Comment: Is there anywhere where something like this is packaged up into a gem, that one could use, instead of copy/pasting or such?  If so, where?  :)

Comment: I prefer this over any gem.

Comment: Is there any way I can check for a specific version of windows, for example Windows 8.1?

Comment: That windows variant regex is off btw, each name should be in parentheses for "|" or to work as expected.

Comment: How can I get this to identify freebsd vs linux?

Comment: How can I get the exact OS name and its version? For example, centos 7.5 or redhat 7.8? Please suggest.

Answer (score 29):

I like this, most people use [rubygems](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Platform.html), its reliable, is cross platform

```
irb(main):001:0> Gem::Platform.local
=> #<Gem::Platform:0x151ea14 @cpu="x86", @os="mingw32", @version=nil>
irb(main):002:0> Gem::Platform.local.os
=> "mingw32"
```

**update** use in conjunction with ["Update! Addition! Rubygems nowadays..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on/40946277#40946277) to mitigate when `Gem::Platform.local.os == 'java'`

Comment: On jruby it just reports "java" so it's not sufficient if you expect to have anyone running jruby.

Answer (score 18):

Either

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'rbconfig'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Config::CONFIG["arch"]
=> "i686-linux"
```

or

```
irb(main):004:0> RUBY_PLATFORM
=> "i686-linux"
```

Comment: Don't you mean `Config::CONFIG[‘host_os’]`?

Comment: "Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config" => ```RbConfig::CONFIG["arch"]```

Comment: @jtzero If you provide a more complete answer in the comments I'l update the answer written in 2008

Comment: in ruby 1.9.3 (p327)  its just that line, ruby has it by default `irb(main):002:0> require 'rbconfig'
=> false`

Comment: When I did it, I got a statement saying that was depreciated. `(irb):10:in `irb_binding': Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.` So I used that, `RbConfig::CONFIG.each` and listed all the different values. Maybe you can find something in there to help you find what you're looking for.

Comment: `RUBY_PLATFORM` is fine. From `Config::CONFIG` though only `target_os` and `host_os` work reliably. As with jruby only they indicate linux.

Answer (score 11):

I have a second answer, to add more options to the fray.
 [The os rubygem](http://rubygems.org/gems/os), and their [github page](https://github.com/rdp/os) has a related projects list.

```
require 'os'

>> OS.windows?
=> true   # or OS.doze?

>> OS.bits
=> 32

>> OS.java?
=> true # if you're running in jruby.  Also OS.jruby?

>> OS.ruby_bin
=> "c:\ruby18\bin\ruby.exe" # or "/usr/local/bin/ruby" or what not

>> OS.posix?
=> false # true for linux, os x, cygwin

>> OS.mac? # or OS.osx? or OS.x?
=> false
```

Answer (score 8):

The **[OS](https://github.com/rdp/os)** gem is the most user-friendly library, offering methods like `OS.mac?` or `OS.posix?`. It's small and depends only on the [Ruby standard library](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/standard_library_rdoc.html).

For something readily accessible in most Ruby installations that is already somewhat processed for you, try these:

1. `Gem.win_platform?` #=> eg. true, false ([code](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/f68cdada86721d3adf4e8c106d277f99d2067cd6/lib/rubygems.rb#L1065-L1072))
2. `Gem::Platform.local.os` #=> eg. "mingw32", "java", "linux", "cygwin", "aix", "dalvik" ([code](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/f68cdada86721d3adf4e8c106d277f99d2067cd6/lib/rubygems/platform.rb#L79..L103))

Both these and every other platform checking script I know is based on interpreting these underlying variables:

1. `RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"]` #=> eg. "linux-gnu" (code [1](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/bd8cb9f5d268881a49819a1996d3dffdb951168e/win32/Makefile.sub#L962), [2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e4f46eabab70bfcde67f0032a902433d11afc166/tool/mkconfig.rb))
2. `RbConfig::CONFIG["arch"]` #=> eg. "i686-linux", "i386-linux-gnu" (passed as [parameter when the Ruby interpreter is compiled](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e4f46eabab70bfcde67f0032a902433d11afc166/tool/mkconfig.rb#L13))
3. `RUBY_PLATFORM` #=> eg. "i386-linux-gnu", "darwin" - *Note that this returns "java" in JRuby!* ([code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/842272540886ff1da58e690907b08f2811a86607/version.c#L63)) These are all Windows variants: `/cygwin|mswin|mingw|bccwin|wince|emx/`
4. `RUBY_ENGINE` #=> eg. "ruby", "jruby"

Other libraries include **[Platform](https://github.com/kraigstrong/platform)**, which can distinguish well between a variety of Unix platforms. `Platform::IMPL` will return, eg. :linux, :freebsd, :netbsd, :hpux. **[sys-uname](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-uname)** and **[sysinfo](https://github.com/delano/sysinfo/blob/master/lib/sysinfo.rb#L16)** are similar. **[utilinfo](https://github.com/ArunSahadeo/utilinfo)** is extremely basic, and will fail on any systems beyond Windows, Mac, and Linux.

If you want more advanced libraries with specific system details, like different Linux distributions, see my answer for [Detecting Linux distribution in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55087176/5389585).

Also, you might consider [feature detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_(web_development)) rather than using trying to sniff the operating system at all.

Comment: I'd welcome more precise explanations or links to how `RUBY_PLATFORM` or `RbConfig::CONFIG["host_os"]` are populated. Looking at the code, it's still not clear to me.

Answer (score 7):

**Try the Launchy gem** (`gem install launchy`):

```
require 'launchy'
Launchy::Application.new.host_os_family # => :windows, :darwin, :nix, or :cygwin
```

Comment: That's Launchy::Application.new.host_os_family in 2.1.0.

Comment: FYI -- Launchy uses rbconfig: https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/blob/master/lib/launchy/detect/host_os.rb

Answer (score 6):

**Update! Addition!** Rubygems nowadays ships with [`Gem.win_platform?`](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/f68cdada86721d3adf4e8c106d277f99d2067cd6/lib/rubygems.rb#L1065-L1072).

[Example usages in the Rubygems repo](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=win_platform%3F), and this one, for clarity:

```
def self.ant_script
  Gem.win_platform? ? 'ant.bat' : 'ant'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'rbconfig'
include Config

case CONFIG['host_os']
  when /mswin|windows/i
    # Windows
  when /linux|arch/i
    # Linux
  when /sunos|solaris/i
    # Solaris
  when /darwin/i
    #MAC OS X
  else
    # whatever
end
```

Comment: I guess this should be `case Config::CONFIG['host_os']` ?

Comment: actually in ruby 2 it should be `RbConfig::Obsolete::CONFIG['host_os']`    ...+no need to include the `Config`

Comment: Change the `include` or both types of Modules, and then this is the best answer IMO. Notice how he `include`'d the Module, so no need for RbConfig or Config.

Answer (score 1):

We have been doing pretty good so far with the following code

```
  def self.windows?
    return File.exist? "c:/WINDOWS" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
    RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32/
  end

  def self.linux?
    return File.exist? "/usr" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
    RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
  end

  def self.os
    return :linux if self.linux?
    return :windows if self.windows?
    nil
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `os` gem, when loading different binaries for IMGKit

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
IMGKit.configure do |config|
  if OS.linux? && OS.host_cpu == "x86_64"
    config.wkhtmltoimage =
      Rails.root.join("bin", "wkhtmltoimage-linux-amd64").to_s
  elsif OS.mac? && OS.host_cpu == "x86_64"
    config.wkhtmltoimage =
      Rails.root.join("bin", "wkhtmltoimage-macos-amd64").to_s
  else
    puts OS.report
    abort "You need to add a binary for wkhtmltoimage for your OS and CPU"
  end
end
```

Answer (score -7):

When I just need to know if it is a Windows or Unix-like OS it is often enough to

```
is_unix = is_win = false
File::SEPARATOR == '/' ? is_unix = true : is_win = true
```

Comment: File::SEPARATOR gives / in windows, so this doesn't work

Comment: Bad practice all around. If you want to know what the file separator is, use `File::SEPARATOR`. It's best to duck-type the platform just like developing in Ruby. But if you have to know whether the platform is Windows, ask the question instead of trying to infer it.