# Ruby How to determine execution environment

Tags: ruby, operating-system, environment-variables

I need to determine what environment my ruby script is running in so I can remove files and clean up directories after execution.

I tried using `ENV['os']` but I am using cygwin and it gave me Windows_NT, Does anyone know a way to find the current environment?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/170956/5389585

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find which operating system my Ruby program is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the gem 'OS' which can be found here: http://rubygems.org/gems/os

I haven't tried it with cygwin, but I did replace my own use of the ENV variable hash with it.

Comment: This question also addresses your problem.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/ruby-how-can-i-find-out-on-which-system-my-program-is-running

Comment: os gem works beautifully. We can do things like `OS::windows?` `OS::linux?`

Answer (score 8):

The current environment is provided by the global constant `RUBY_PLATFORM`

ruby invoked at the cygwin bash shell (/usr/bin/ruby):

```
puts RUBY_PLATFORM
i386-cygwin
```

ruby invoked at the command prompt (c:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe):

```
puts RUBY_PLATFORM
i386-mingw32
```

`puts ENV['OS']` for both of the above environment returns: `Windows_NT`

Answer (score 3):

The current os can be obtained from RUBY_PLATFORM

```
puts RUBY_PLATFORM
X86_64-linux
```

However, when I use ENV['os'] on Linux machine, Ruby returns nil.