# Check if DOS or bash from inside web app

Tags: bash, dos

Say I have a web application, with some sort of system execution. I'm going to use Ruby for this example. This app could be portable and installed on either a Windows or Unix server. If the app uses system commands, is there a way to distinguish what platform the server is, then maybe catch in an `if` statement?

Theoretically like this:

```
os_check = `checkos` # System ticks to execute through the shell
                     # using fake command

if os_check == 'unix'
  # Run Unix Commands
  `ls -la`
else if os_check == 'dos'
  # Run DOS commands
  `dir`
else
  puts 'OS not detectable'
end
```

**EDIT**

I'm not looking for Ruby specifically (removed the tag). That was an example. I was hoping for a shell command that could execute in both environments and be variable based on what the OS is. I actually have to replicate this sort of function in several languages. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby How to determine execution environment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523038/ruby-how-to-determine-execution-environment)

Comment: @gpojd Negative. Not looking for a Ruby-only answer.

Comment: @KyleMacey: what is your target technology?  Each language is likely to have its own way of detecting the host Operating System; I doubt that there is a technique that works universally.

Comment: @maerics Well I was thinking something along the lines of testing `cd /opt` which would only work in Unix. Or even `ping` responds differently in both platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking the [`RUBY_PLATFORM` global constant](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#pre-defined-global-constants):

```ruby
case RUBY_PLATFORM
  when /win32/ then # Windows, use "dir"
  # when /darwin/ then # Mac OS X
  # when /linux/ then # Linux
  else # Assume "ls" on all other platforms
end
```

**[Edit]** Per your updated question, you might be able to issue the system command `echo /?` and parse the output to determine the host OS.  The "echo" command should exist on most systems but Windows interprets the `/?` switch as the "help" message whereas UNIX OSes simply echo those characters.  For example (again in Ruby, just to demonstrate the general strategy):

```ruby
def detect_host_operating_system
  (%x{echo /?} =~ /^\/\?\r?\n$/) ? 'unix' : 'windows'
end
```

Comment: The only time you may run into an issue with this is using jRuby, which I believe will report "java" regardless of the underlying platform.

Comment: Please see my edit. +1 for Ruby solution

Comment: YES! Along the lines of what I was thinking and should be universal!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple. Try running a command that only exists on the desired platform

dos: `cmd`

nix: `man`

The result status of some trival run with no arguments is the key here.

With this method there is no string parsing. Which is more optimized.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it with Python, this scripting language is installed by default on most Linux distributions and Mac (I think also on Unix systems like BSD, but I am not completely sure about that).

```
import os

if (os.name == "posix"):
    #run unix command
else:
    #run Windows command
```

You can also add more OS checks if you like, of course.