# How to detect Windows XP using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operating-system, detection

Working on a game atm using Ruby, but due to the nature of how the game is coded Windows XP is proving to be a issue, as various tweaks can be done to make you faster than other players
so my intentions are to upon loading of the game detect if you are running windows XP, and if so fail to load any further.

This may seem harsh, but the advantages XP gives over Vista or Win7 etc is vast and is unbalanced.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you find some solutions on how to detect the operating system:

[How can I find which operating system my Ruby program is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on)

But I think, it only tells you, if it is Windows or not. So you have to do a second step:

If it is Windows, you could call the system command `ver` to detect the Windows Version (As you might know, system commands can be called using the `-Symbol).

```
`ver`
```

More information about this command are found here: http://www.windows-commandline.com/2009/01/find-windows-os-version-from-command.html