# Best way to handle OS differences with rake sh command

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying write a build script with rake which will run on Windows and Linux. Assume that I have the following rake task:

```
task:check do
    sh "dir"
end
```

This will work on Windows but not in other operating systems. What is the best way to handle operating system differences with `sh` command? I specifically want to make following task work between operating systems but it currently on works on Windows:

```
task:check do
    %w(npm bower kpm gulp).each do |cmd|
        begin sh "#{cmd} --version > NUL" rescue raise "#{cmd} doesn't exists globally" end
    end
end
```

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of "[How can I find which operating system my Ruby program is running on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on)"

Comment: @theTinMan not entirely. Check out the excepted answer.

Comment: "almost a duplicate", not "a duplicate", otherwise I'd have closed it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [os gem](https://github.com/rdp/os).  You could wrap your task definitions in checks for the platform, or even use some of the helpers to write more generic tasks.

Something like this may be handy:

```
>> OS.dev_null
=> "NUL" # or "/dev/null" depending on which platform
```

Or just make them specific to the OS:

```
if OS.windows?

  task :whatever do
    # ...
  end

elsif OS.linux?

  task :whatever do
    # ...
  end

end
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! went with this: `sh "#{cmd} --version >> #{OS.dev_null}"`

Comment: Note that this gem [treats Cygwin as Linux](https://github.com/rdp/os/blob/master/lib/os.rb#L5), not Windows! Depending on your use-case this might not be what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Ruby knows the OS it was compiled on, and what it's running on, because it has to be aware of path delimiters, line-ending characters, etc. We can find out about what it knows using built-in constants and/or modules.

Using the `RUBY_PLATFORM` constant:

On Mac OSX:

```
RUBY_PLATFORM # => "x86_64-darwin13.0"
```

On Linux:

```
RUBY_PLATFORM # => "x86_64-linux"
```

You can also use Gem::Platform:

On Mac OSX:

```
Gem::Platform.local # => #<Gem::Platform:0x3fe859440ef4 @cpu="x86_64", @os="darwin", @version="13">
Gem::Platform.local.os # => "darwin"
```

And on Linux:

```
Gem::Platform.local # => #<Gem::Platform:0x13e0b60 @cpu="x86_64", @os="linux", @version=nil>
Gem::Platform.local.os # => "linux"
```

And then there's the RbConfig module that comes with Ruby:

On Mac OS:

```
RbConfig::CONFIG['target_cpu']   # => "x86_64"
RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os']    # => "darwin13.0"
RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu']     # => "x86_64"
RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']      # => "darwin13.4.0"
```

And on Linux:

```
 RbConfig::CONFIG['target_cpu'] # => "x86_64"
 RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os']  # => "linux"
 RbConfig::CONFIG['host_cpu']   # => "x86_64"
 RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']    # => "linux-gnu"
```

[A quick search](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=5oxKVPKqIML1oASj34CABQ&ved=0CAcQ1S4#q=RUBY_PLATFORM%20windows) returns a number of hits for this, including many here on Stack Overflow.