# Finding out what OS is being run through a program

Tags: ruby, operating-system

From a program created in Ruby is it possible to find out what OS the user is running from within the program?

For example could you check for a systems32 folder and from there decide that the user is running windows and use batch commands, or check for a root folder or something that all linux machines run and use bash commands instead?

Comment: Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on Idk how to mark as duplicate so..