# Cron Job not working for shell script or ruby script mac os

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, cron

I have a ruby script called `automated_script.rb`

I also have a shell script called `automated_script.sh`

Both of these files are located on my desktop, for now.

whenever I run `ruby automated_script.rb`, the script works as expected (all it does is send a text message using the twilio api)

This is what I have in `automated_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/zsh

/Users/angelgarcia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby /Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.rb
```

when I navigate to my desktop in the terminal and run, `./automated_script.sh` it works.

when I simply run:

```
/Users/angelgarcia/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby /Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.rb
```

in the terminal, this works too.

**However**, in my crontab, I have this:

```
* * * * * /Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.sh
```

This does not work as expected.

Simply running this works: `/Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.sh`
But for some reason, when I put it in the crontab, it doesn't run every minute.

When I run `crontab -l` in my terminal, I get this:

```
* * * * * /Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.sh
```

So I know it's active.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**

here is whats inside of my ruby file

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = 'xxx'
auth_token = 'xxx'
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

@client.messages.create(
  from: '999',
  to: '999',
  body: message 
)
```

Comment: You could check for errors in cron's log files. A common error is to use relative paths instead of absolute, for example in your automated_script.rb.

Comment: It might also be helpful if we can see what automated_script.rb is doing.

Comment: @Sergio I'll try checking those, thanks

Comment: @lacostenycoder I've added the ruby script

Comment: The crontab are configured to the same user that you try run directly? In some cases, if the user differs, can be permission problems

Comment: Don't use cron on macOS, use launchd. https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/12819/197811

Comment: @WilliamPrigolLopes is there any way to check this? There's only one user on my machine. I'm trying to put this on a server, or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need shell to execute ruby from cron.  You should be able to just pass ruby and a file to your crontab.

```
* * * * * ruby /Users/angelgarcia/Desktop/automated_script.rb
```

Note, this will use whatever your default system ruby version is set to.

Comment: Is there anyway I could run the shell? I'm using the shell script as a wrapper because i want to run that ruby script conditionally. Part of that condition has to do with the operating system, which i feel would be much easier to access with a shell script than with a ruby script.

Comment: How is that easier in shell?  Also, how can you assume the user running your script is running zsh ? Can you post your shell script code? See answer to this question for how to check OS in ruby. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170956/how-can-i-find-which-operating-system-my-ruby-program-is-running-on

Comment: The script is only for me to run on my machine, and I said OS but perhaps I should've been more specific. It's more to see what I'm doing on my terminal. I feel more comfortable with performing those checks using a shell script, and I'd rather go with that option. Furthermore, independent of the fact that I wanna use the shell script, the answer you gave me isn't working.

Comment: @AngelGarcia please check the output of `rvm list`. If the default ruby version is set correctly to the same version required by your ruby script, and the gems which your script may require are installed in that version, you should not need to pass the full path of the ruby binary.  If the default ruby version doesn't match, your ruby script will likely fail. Also you'll want to make sure your shell script has been made executable. `chmod +x automated_script.sh`.